# Trying to show object state in plone gives a "No workflow provides '${name}' information." error

Tags: python, plone, zope

I'm trying to return an objects state using the following code:

```
workflow = getToolByName(context,'portal_workflow')
status = workflow.getInfoFor(obj,'review_state')
```

When I try to output this using:

```
print "State: %s" % (status)
```

I get the following error:

> Exception Type Workflow
>
> Exception Exception Value No workflow provides '${name}' information.

I've done a little reading around the web but nothing seems to give a definitive answer.

Can anyone help?

**EDIT**
This is not down to an object not having workflow. The object im trying to get the state for is using custom workflow. However switching this to using the default plone workflow still troughs the same error.

**FIXED**
After just trying the simplest thing out:

`status = obj.review_state`

This works! go figure. Thanks anyway.

Moderators you can delete this post if you wish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, Giacomo's answer is correct. The `obj` you were trying to pass to the `getInfoFor` method is a catalog brain, not an actual content object. That is why asking for it's `review_state` directly worked for you.

A Plone content object has no knowledge of it's own workflow state. That information is maintained by the workflow tool, which is why when you are looking at an actual content object you must use `workflow_tool.getInfoFor`

In your case, you've taken the result of a catalog search, which is a lightweight structure called a `brain`, and tried to pass it to the workflow tool. Catalog brains do not have workflow, so the error you got is perfectly accurate. But a catalog brain does have a `review_state` attribute, which corresponds to the review state of the object represented by the catalog brain.

In short, if you have a catalog brain, use `brain.review_state`, if you have a content object, use `workflow_tool.getInfoFor(obj, 'review_state')`

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are trying to get the workflow state of an object that doesn't have any associated workflow (probably a File or an Image). You can check in zmi->portal_workflows all of the contenttype-workflows pairings.

Comment: Not true. Im trying to do it on a document that does have workflow.

Comment: Although it is using a custom workflow, i wonder if this makes any difference?

Comment: Nope, not that as i've just set it to `(Default)` and i get the same error.

Comment: did you also "update(d) security settings" (the botton at the end of the page)?

Answer (score 0):

In the variables tab of your definition (ZMI for portal_workflow), at the bottom of that page, make sure that state variable name is 'review_state' -- this may not be the default, IIRC.  This may be one possible source of your problem.